# Serial port in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, serial-port

I'm trying to write a program to interpret traffic received from a serial interface under Cygwin. I copied some demo code from another project to open the serial port. Then I set up the serial port speed to the baudrate used by the serial port (921600).

```
static int serial_open(char *portname)
{
    int FD_com; // file descriptor for the serial port
    struct termios term;

    FD_com = open(portname, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (FD_com == -1) // if open is unsuccessful
    {
        printf("serial_open: Unable to open %s.\n", portname);
    }
    else
    {
        // set speed of port
        cfsetspeed(&term, BAUDRATE);

        // set to 8-bits, no parity, 1 stop bit
        term.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        term.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        term.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        term.c_cflag |= CS8;

        term.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
        tcsetattr(FD_com, TCSANOW, &term);
    }
    return(FD_com);
}
```

Then I tried to capture the traffic in a file

```
    if (FD_ISSET(FD_com, &fds))
    {
        // wait for data to come in on the serial port
        if ((nbytes = read(FD_com, port_buf, PORTBUFSIZE)) > 0)
        {
            for (i=0; i<nbytes; i++)
            {
                fwrite(&port_buf[i], 1, sizeof(uint8_t), fout);
```

The problem is, the traffic recorded in the file lost some bytes. The longest consecutive string it can record is over 48 bytes, but most other strings, it wraps around with 48 bytes. I assume that this because of buffer overflow. But how to configure the serial port rx buffer? The `port_buf` defined in the application is 512 (PORTBUFSIZE)bytes, which should be big enough.

Comment: This is confusing. Did you "lose some bytes", or did long lines get broken into short chunks (e.g., "`The quick brown fox jumps over t`" + "`he lazy dog.`")? What do you mean by "The longest consecutive string it can record is over 48 bytes..."? Why are you using `O_NDELAY`? If you don't need it, try taking it out and see what happens. And the obvious (stupid) question is: what is `PORTBUFSIZE` defined as?

Comment: Scott, I had updated the question. I'm testing with some binary messages. The messages are sent in bursts and each has a different length. Some messages only have first 48 bytes recorded. The PORTBUFSIZE is 512 bytes. I'm using O_NDELAY as no DCD signal is needed, so delay feature is disabled. I add one line to not wait for serial port as `term.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;`, and now the wrap around problem is solved. But I still have one or two bytes lost in some messages. I tried to use `cat /dev/ttyS0 > test.log` to capture log directly from command line. The method also loses one byte from time to time

Comment: BTW, the similar method under Microsoft C# is OK without byte losses